# UIWebView can't inject HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to put some HTML in a div in a UIWebView. Although the code seems correct it won't work.

This works:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"testdiv\").innerHTML = \"Test text here\""]];
```

This doesn't:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"testdiv\").innerHTML = \"%@\"", htmlString]];
```

In the second case 'htmlString' is just some HTML within a blockquote.

Basically when I do it with the HTML it fails. My first thought it that the HTML could be invalid but I thought it would still attempt to display it.

The 'error' I'm getting as a result of the operation is just an empty (non-nil) string.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here is an example of the HTML that won't display:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 20px;"></div><div><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html charset=us-ascii" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body style=
"word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;"
class="">
TestTESTEST<br class="" />
<div apple-content-edited="true" class="">
<div style=
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;"
class="">
<div class="" style="font-size: 10px;"><br class="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

The htmlString variable is just that HTML within a blockquote tag.

Edit 2:

If I take the HTML and put it directly in the document and then load it it works. It's only having issues when I try to insert it via JS.

Comment: I have only one idea about this: you provide invalid Html. So remove all newline characters and check for not closed tags.

Comment: May be your data is terminating in between the escaped characters?, Can you check using `NSLog`?

Comment: also check your data in browser's debug console

Comment: Would invalid HTML cause nothing to display? @iphonic I NSLog the result of stringByEval and get an empty string returned. I also get nothing in webViewFailed delegate.

Comment: can you provide example of `htmlString` that doesn't work ?

Comment: @sage444 working on that now, I'll post something in a few minutes.

Comment: @sage444 done. The HTML is taken from an email and displays correctly in a UIWebView via the loadHTMLString method.

Comment: Now we can see that you load whole html document into div, I'm not sore that it's valid structure, but to ensure try to load only content from between `<body></body>`

Comment: @sage444 Still the same problem just loading the body tags content.

Comment: hmm, last idea, can you try single quotes in string format: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"testdiv\").innerHTML = '%@'", htmlString]];`

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere.  If I take the content between the body tags (and exclude the body tags) and use single quotes in the string format the stringByEvaluating method returns the content. I'm guessing your original diagnosis of invalid HTML is the problem so I'll look into that a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

As the HTML document I want to insert into is just a template I'm copying it into the code and just building the entire string and loading it into the UIWebView:

e.g. `NSString *s = @"<html><body><div1></div1><div2>%@</div2></body></html>", contentToInsert.`

Ideally I still want to get this working as if I can insert the HTML via JS I can use multiple HTML templates and just fit the content into them as needed. So if you can find a solution please let me know.